# Gravity Forms Webhooks

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I have a Gravity Forms form that is posting to an external API via the Webhooks add-on. In the response from the API there is a redirect URL. I am looking for the best way to grab that dynamic URL and use it for my redirect after the form is submitted.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please check with the official support streams for Gravity Forms and/or the webhook add-on.

Comment: While I appreciate the response, your answer defeats the whole purpose of posting in this forum.

Comment: At the link ([help/on-topic]) you will find a short note about the scope of help.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the scope. Is the official support stream the only place to ask a question like this? Thank you.